# oracle sql regexp removing the letter t

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

table:

```
USERID | EMAILADRESS 
1      | tiffany.last@gmail.com
2      | tim.someone@gmail.com
3      | john.doe@gmail.com
```

I am running an update statement on this table

```sql
UPDATE table SET EMAILADRESS = LOWER(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(EMAILADRESS, '(^[[:space:]]+)|([[:space:]]+$)',null), '(^[[:cntrl:]^\t]+)|([[:cntrl:]^\t]+$)',null))
```

I am getting the following end result:

```
USERID | EMAILADRESS 
1      | iffany.last@gmail.com
2      | im.someone@gmail.com
3      | john.doe@gmail.com
```

only thing that I am trying to do is to trim any spaces and tabs. why is the t getting deleted?

Comment: removing `^\t` fixes the problem for me. is this a safe solution?

Comment: Tabs are included in both the `:space:` and `:cntrl:` character classes, so why are you trying to handle that explicitly with `\t`; and if you only have spaces and tabs to worry about, why are you using `:cntrl:` at all? Also do you really mean you only want to trim them from either end, and want to preserve any in the middle on an address?

Comment: yes. I want to preserve in the middle on an address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're inside a pattern the `\` and `t` are seen as separate characters and both are excluded. You can avoid that by concatenating in `chr(9)` to represent an actual tab character, rather than trying to use `\t`.

But both the `:space:` and `:cntrl:` [character classes](https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/regex/character-classes/) include tabs already, so you don't need to handle those separately with `\t` or `chr(9)` anyway.

If you want to remove all whitespace and all control characters from the start and end then you can do:

```
regexp_replace(emailadress, '(^[[:space:][:cntrl:]]+|[[:space:][:cntrl:]]+$)', null)
```

but if you are only actually interested in whitespace - including tabs, but not other control characters - then you only need:

```
regexp_replace(emailadress, '(^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$)', null)
```

If you only actually want to trim actual space characters and tabs, not all whitespace (e.g. line feeds), then you can use nested `trim()` calls instead:

```
trim(both ' ' from trim(both chr(9) from emailadress))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4fca070250424f92428d7b340f0bcdd9) showing spaces and tabs being trimmed from the ends, but preserved in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest focusing on the letters you want to keep:

```
select regexp_replace(emailaddress, '[^-_a-zA-Z.@]', '', 1, 1, 'g')
```

Comment: too many parameters for oracle. this worked for me: ```regexp_replace(EMAILADRESS, '[^-_a-zA-Z.@]', null)```

Comment: @syrkull . . . The number of parameters is correct for Oracle:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Since regexp can get complicated you can go for translate also:

```
UPDATE table SET EMAILADRESS = translate(EMAILADDRESS, chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), '    ');
```

This would replace all special characters like tab,line feeds from your text and make your code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just `trim` + `regexp_replace(..., '[[:cntrl:]]')`:

```sql
with t(USERID, EMAILADRESS) as (
select 1, 'tiffany.last@'||chr(9)||'gmail.com' from dual union all
select 2, 'tim.some'||chr(9)||'one@gmail.com' from dual union all
select 3, 'john.doe@gmail.com' from dual union all
select 4, 'Steven.'||chr(9)||'King@gmail.com' from dual
)
select 
   EMAILADRESS,
   regexp_replace(lower(trim(EMAILADRESS)), '[[:cntrl:]]') new_email
from t;
```